# Quartz.NET Connection-transaction pair cannot be null

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net

When I look at the event logs for my windows-service based Quartz.NET project, I get:

`Connection-Transaction Pair cannot be null`

`parameter name: cth`

I googled, of course, but didn't find any documentation whatsoever on the exception. Does anybody know what this means or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: here's the extended (but still not complete) exception/stack trace:

`Service cannot be started. Parameters: refire = False, unscheduleFiringTrigger = False, unscheduleAllTriggers = False Quartz.JobExecutionException: System.ArgumentNullException: Connnection-transaction pair cannot be null Parameter name: cth at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.CheckNotZombied(ConnectionAndTransactionHolder cth) in c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line 3487 at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.RollbackConnection(ConnectionAndTransactionHolder cth) in c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line 3300 at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.ExecuteInNonManagedTXLock(String lockName, Func2 txCallback) in c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line 3467 at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX.ExecuteInLock(String lockName, Func2 txCallback) in c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreTX.cs:line 76 at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.Store...`

Also, is there a way to get the full stack trace? I can't do it programmatically because it fails before the service even starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place `Debugger.Launch();` above the first line of your windows service code so when you start the service you'll be able to step through the code and find the exact line of code where exception is thrown...

Comment: Doesn't help if the program never makes it that far. And doesn't help because for whatever insane reason, my company doesn't feel like JIT compiler is worth elevating to admin-status via ViewFinity.

Comment: But thank you, because you reminded me to complain to somebody about that

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, also tried the bugfix Sanjay10 proposed, but didn't work. This just deferred the problem to a different position.

This error occurs if Quartz tries to rollback the connection, because some error occured while attempting to create a valid connection to the database. I my case this did not work because my database was not configured to allow remote connections (was a local hastily set up test DB). Switching to another (well-tested) database solved the problem for me.

**So my suggestion is that it's either the same problem as I had or some other DB-related problem (like the assigned user lacks some permissions). Possibly try another DB or give the assigned user more permissions**

Answer (score 1):

Get the latest Quartz.net libraries.   They have fixed this bug.

Here is the change set for this

https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/commit/e1a136cf5ac5c525cf0b9514e190e6b1132ffe48#src/Quartz/Impl/AdoJobStore/JobStoreSupport.cs